# notifyDataSetChanged doesn't refresh RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a weird problem. I switched to `RecyclerView` from `ListView` and I can't refresh or notify of change in my `ListView`. I tried calling `Item.this.notifyDataSetChanged();`
and other methods to refresh `View` but it doesn't work.
Instead `RecyclerView` is refreshed when I scroll(regardless of direction). How can I notify my `RecyclerView` when there is a change?

CODE:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Ids holder, final int position) {
    rowItemClass = (ListViewRow) rowItems.get(position);
    Log.e("swag", "OYOYOYOYOYO");
    if (Globals.isPlaying && Globals.pos == position) {

        if (pausedSamePos == true) {
            holder.pauseed_play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.playing_pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.pauseed_play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.playing_pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        holder.song_currenttime_sb.setActive();
        holder.song_duration.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.song_duration_sb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.seekbar.setActive();

    } else {
        holder.seekbar.setInactive();
        holder.song_currenttime_sb.setInactive();
        holder.song_icon.setImageResource(rowItemClass.getImageId());
        holder.song_duration_sb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.song_duration.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.pauseed_play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.playing_pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
    sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();

    holder.song_duration.setTypeface(Globals
            .getTypefaceSecondary(context));
    holder.song_duration_sb.setTypeface(Globals
            .getTypefaceSecondary(context));
    holder.song_name.setTypeface(Globals.getTypefacePrimary(context));
    holder.song_currenttime_sb.setTypeface(Globals
            .getTypefaceSecondary(context));

    holder.song_name.setText(rowItemClass.getTitle());
    holder.song_duration.setText(rowItemClass.getDesc());

    holder.song_duration_sb.setText(rowItemClass.getDesc());
    holder.favorite.setTag(position);
    holder.song_currenttime_sb.setTag(position);
    holder.seekbar.setTag(position);
    holder.clickRegister.setTag(position);
    holder.song_icon.setTag(position);
    holder.song_name.setTag(position);
    holder.song_duration.setTag(position);
    holder.song_duration_sb.setTag(position);
    holder.more_options.setTag(position);
    // int task_id = (Integer) holder.seekbar.getTag();
    final Ids finalHolder = holder;





    holder.clickRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {

                if ((Globals.isPlaying.booleanValue())
                        && (Globals.pos == position)) {
                    pausePlaying();

                } else {

                    Globals.stopPlaying();
                    pausedSamePos = false;
                    Globals.pos = position;
                    Globals.isPlaying = true;
                    Item.this.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    Globals.mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, Integer
                            .valueOf(Item.this.songPos[position])
                            .intValue());
                    Globals.mp.start();
                    Globals.pos = position;

                    Globals.isPlaying = Boolean.valueOf(true);
                    Item.this.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    Globals.mp
                            .setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompletion(
                                        MediaPlayer mpOnComplete) {
                                    mpOnComplete.release();

                                    Globals.isPlaying = false;
                                    pausedSamePos = false;
                                    Globals.isPlaying = Boolean
                                            .valueOf(false);
                                    finalHolder.menu_options
                                            .startAnimation(new ViewExpandAnimation(
                                                    finalHolder.menu_options));
                                    Item.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            });

                }
            } catch (Exception localException) {
            }

        }
    });

    holder.clickRegister
            .setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    Globals.stopPlaying();
                    Item.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    return true;
                }
            });




}
```

Comment: if you are using viewholder pattern in your list views there is actually no real advantage in using recycler views imo

Comment: Well It's supposed to be better for animations. Besides it does work better in FragmentView. Old ListView was calling GetView method even when nothing was happening and that resulted in very poor performance.

Comment: can you post recycler adapter code

Comment: @Ramesh Code posted.

Comment: what is `Item`? Have you tried using only `notifyDataSetChanged();` in place of `Item.this.notifyDataSetChanged();`.

Comment: Item is class name. And yes, it's pretty much same thing. Nothing changes until  List is scrolled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why is this, but `notifyDataSetChanged();` didn't work. So I tried keeping track of changed items and refreshing them manually with `notifyItemChanged(int);` and so far it seems to be working. I am still not sure why refreshing whole `RecyclerView` didn't work.

Answer (score 12):

I've been struggling hard with a similar issue, trying to handle a use-case where all of the adapter's content has to be replaced and the recycler-view should *start from scratch*: calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`, `swapAdapter()` with numerous combinations of subsequent calls to view/layout-manager invalidation requests resulted in nothing but a (seemingly) empty recycler-view. The view didn't even try to rebind the view holders.

What seemed to have worked it out is this hack-ish fix:

```
view.swapAdapter(sameAdapter, true);
view.scrollBy(0, 0);
```

As it turns out, `scrollBy` (even with 0 offsets) drives the recycler-view into laying out its views and executing the pending view-holders rebinding.

Comment: oh damn dude, you can't imagine how this problem was driving me crazy. Randomly, notifyDataSetChanged worked, and sometimes it didn't, but as soon as I scrolled a bit with my fingers, it got updated. .scrollBy(0, 0) does perfectly the trick, but there is definitely something wrong in the RecyclerView code. Thaanks!

Comment: You and me both, @SimonNinon :-) Happy to help!

Comment: Thanks for this answer, and a side note on why this works - it calls RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations() so that pending updates are executed.

Answer (score 2):

if you want notify your recycleListView just simple call notifyDataSetChanged(); in your class adapter. this is my method in my adapter class :

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Listdapter.ViewHolder> {
....
private List<DesaObject> desaObjects= new ArrayList<DesaObject>();

public void setListObjects(List<DesaObject> desaObjects){
        if(this.desaObjects.size()>0)
            this.desaObjects.clear();
        this.desaObjects = desaObjects;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
....

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
       public final View mView;
       public final AppCompatTextView desa;


       public ViewHolder(View view) {
           super(view);
           mView = view;
           desa = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desa);
       }

   }
}
```

in your code you dont actually set or change your listObjects in the OnClickListener and please try notifyDataSetChanged(); instead of Item.this.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Well I do set state of some objects, some objects are initialized to update(text/seekbar)other objects are set visible, all that works, except for the updating part. SeekBar and TextView are not updated until view is scrolled(they are updated but progress is not displayed) And changing to `notifyDataSetChanged();` changes nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your Adapter Again with changed data and use method 'swapadapter'. hope it helps.