# RecyclerView not updated with notifyDatasetChanged till Scrolled upwards

Tags: android, pagination, android-recyclerview

I am using gridLayoutManager on my recycler view and want to implement pagination on it. My problem is that when i reach the bottom of the view and add data from the service and i use notifyDataSetChanged or notifyItemRangeChanged the recyclerView do not update till i scroll it upwards. And if i set the adapter again and set the position to the previous position the there is a flickering effect, which is not smooth. this is what i tried, but nothing seems to be working

```
//adding data to my list
mNewsList.addAll((List<NewDataModel>) response.body());

// i set the adapter again
int currentPosition = 
gaggeredGridLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(mNewsList, Utilities.getThin(getActivity()), (AppCompatActivity) getActivity(), mHeaderTextView.getText().toString());            
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);         
gaggeredGridLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(currentPosition+1);
```

And

```
//adding data to my list
mNewsList.addAll((List<NewDataModel>) response.body());
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And

```
adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0,adapter.getItemCount());
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38140858/recyclerview-updates-only-on-scroll

Comment: @TanujYadav as i said i tried using `notifyItemRangeChanged`  which didn't help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid flickering effect you have to use handler, after adapter set

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {

    //do anything

    rv_products.scrollToPosition(lastPos);
  }
}, 100);
```

I have implement pagination using following way

```
rv_products.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

  @Override
  public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

    visibleItemCount = rv_products.getChildCount();
    if (productListAdapter.getViewType() == 1)
      totalItemCount = mGridLayoutManager.getItemCount();
    else
      totalItemCount = mSingleLayoutManager.getItemCount();

    if (productListAdapter.getViewType() == 1)
      firstVisibleItem = mGridLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    else
      firstVisibleItem = mSingleLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

    if (loading) {
      if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
        loading = false;
        previousTotal = totalItemCount;
      }
    }
    if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)
          <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {

    if (lstProducts.size() < totalCount)
      getProducts(category_id);

      loading = true;
    }
  }
});


public void getProducts(String id) {


  pDialog.setCancelable(false);
  pDialog.show();
  PreferenceSetting preferenceSetting = PreferenceSetting.getInstance(activity);
  Map<String, String> postParam = new HashMap<String, String>();
  postParam.put("category_id", id);
  postParam.put("customer_id", preferenceSetting.getCustomerId());
  postParam.put("eventName", Constants.EVENT_GET_PRODUCTS);
  postParam.put("page", (pageIndex++) + "");

  CommonUtility.setLog("getProducts", postParam.toString());
  JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
      Constants.Server_URL, new JSONObject(postParam),
          new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
              Log.e(getBaseActivity().getLocalClassName(), response.toString());
              pDialog.dismiss();
              try {
                String message = response.getString(Constants.KEY_MESSAGE);
                if (response.getString(Constants.KEY_STATUS).equals(Constants.VALUE_STATUS_SUCCESS)) {
                  Gson gson = new Gson();
                  ProductsReponse productsReponse = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), ProductsReponse.class);
                  ((MainActivity) activity).setCartListCount(productsReponse.getData().getCartItemCount());
                  lstProducts.addAll(productsReponse.getData().getProductDetail());
                  totalCount = Integer.parseInt(productsReponse.getData().getTotalItem());
                  productListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                  tv_count.setText("(" + totalCount + " items)");

                } else {
                  // CommonUtility.ShowToast(activity, message, "");
                }
              } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

              }


            }
          }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
              pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }) {

            /**
             * Passing some request headers
             */
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
              HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
              headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
              return headers;
            }


        };

  // Adding request to request queue
  MyApp.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
}
```

Comment: is setting the adapter again the best way to do it and then handling the scroll with the handler?? The smoothest way??

Comment: if data is approx 2000 then its fine otherwise notifydatasetchanged has to be used.

Comment: In my getProducts function i have used notifyDataSetChanged and its working

Comment: i am doing the same thing, as i am adding the response to my list and then using 'notifyDataSetChanged()' but then also the items only show up after i scroll and sometimes if they show up directly there is a flickering effect.

Comment: after notifiydatasetchange call      Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    //do anything

                                    rv_products.scrollToPosition(lastPos);
                                }
                            }, 100);

Comment: ok, i will try that and then revert you back if there is any problem or it worked for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148336/discussion-between-anmol-and-rajesh-nasit).

Comment: from tommrrow morning

Comment: hello, so can you help me in solving the flickering problem that i am facing?

Comment: I can help but two days i am so busy. can you postpone it

Comment: i'll keep trying till then.

Comment: there is still little bit of flickering in one of my fragment, actually i am really confused that i am using same recyclerView and same code for all categories for which i am loading the data in list, and i am facing the flickering problem only in one of them, rest is working fine.

Comment: Following solution worked for me, if anyone wants to try https://stackoverflow.com/a/42549611/3422488